# 3sum Solution not passing test case (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to program a solution to the 3sum question on leetcode(link: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/).

This is what I've done so far:

```
public int binary_search(int [] nums, int start, int end, int target)
{
    if (start > end)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (nums[mid] == target)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    else {
        if (nums[mid] < target)
        {
            return binary_search(nums, mid + 1, end, target);
        } else {
            return binary_search(nums, start, mid - 1, target);
        }
    }
}

public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> solution_set = new ArrayList();
    Set<List<Integer>> ordered_solutions = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 == nums.length)
        {
            continue;
        }
        int number_1 = nums[i];
        int number_2 = nums[i+1];
        int target = -(number_1 + number_2);

        int target_index = binary_search(nums, 0, nums.length - 1, target);
        if (binary_search(nums, 0, nums.length - 1, target) != -1 && target_index != i && target_index != i+1)
        {
            List<Integer> submission = new ArrayList();

            submission.add(number_1); submission.add(number_2); submission.add(target);
            List<Integer> ordered_submission = submission;
            Collections.sort(ordered_submission);
            if (ordered_solutions.add(ordered_submission) == true)
            {
                solution_set.add(submission);
            }
        }
    }
    return solution_set;
}
```

The program works as follows:
input is given to function threeSum which is then sorted and two following objects are created; An ArrayList that will store all non-duplicate solutions and a Set that is used to test for said duplicate solutions.

Then, the for loop sifts through the array and does the following:
it adds the i and i+1 element then negates them to find the number needed to sum all three numbers to zero. With this number acquired, a binary search is conducted on the array to see if this number can be found. If it is found, a few other conditions are tested to ensure that the target index is not actually the same as index i or i+1. After that, I create two objects, a submission that includes the elements in their original order and an ordered submission. If the ordered submission is inserted into the set and the set returns true, it means it's not a duplicate and i store it in the solution_set.

My problem is as follows: My program fails with the test case [0,0,0]. I believe the target is calculated as zero, but the binary search chooses the zero which is in i+1 so the solution is rejected. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this problem can be fixed?

Comment: Why did you choose binary search solution? This one doesn't work for you https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/7380/Concise-O(N2)-Java-solution ?

Comment: you can simply break the binary search into 2 intervals (0, i - 1) and (i + 2, length - 1) then combine the result to pass that particular case. But I don't think your solution is correct though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you want to do it with binary search, here it is. I've fixed several logical bugs, made some improvements, and added some comments, hope this will help. The code is accepted by leetcode, but it is not so efficient solution. Time complexity is O(n^2*logn). With [2 pointers approach](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/7380/Concise-O(N2)-Java-solution) you can do it in O(n^2).

```
public int binary_search(int[] nums, int start, int end, int target) {
    if (start > end) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (nums[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    } else {
        if (nums[mid] < target) {
            return binary_search(nums, mid + 1, end, target);
        } else {
            return binary_search(nums, start, mid - 1, target);
        }
    }
}

public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> solution_set = new ArrayList<>();

    // you can't do it using only one loop.
    // Take a look at this sample input -2,0,1,1,2.
    // Here you have to consider for nums[i] and nums[j] -2, 0 as well as
    // -2, 1
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
        // skip duplicates
        if (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) {
            continue;
        }

        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length - 1; j++) {
            int number_1 = nums[i];
            int number_2 = nums[j];

            // skip duplicates and, since array is sorted, don't need to
            // consider values > 0
            if (i != j - 1 && nums[j - 1] == nums[j] || number_1 + number_2 > 0)
                continue;

            int target = -(number_1 + number_2);

            // since array is sorted, start binary search only from j + 1
            int target_index = binary_search(nums, j + 1, nums.length - 1, target);
            if (target_index != -1) {
                List<Integer> submission = new ArrayList<>();

                submission.add(number_1);
                submission.add(number_2);
                submission.add(target);
                solution_set.add(submission);
            }
        }
    }

    return solution_set;
}
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0]]
[[-2, 0, 2], [-2, 1, 1]]
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergei! You're also right, the solution you linked is both more efficient and far more clear. Thanks for your input!